# Is there a transpose script available in PHP

Tags: php, excel, transpose

I have my data in excel similar to

[image]

If we select, copy those cells. Then transpose it, we get the below result
(Select any other cell, right click, paste special, transpose) This is how we transpose in excel

[image]

I need a PHP script, which will read my excel like first image, transpose and give me a csv file like image 2. The excel can do the transpose, but can any script do?

Comment: _If we select, copy those cells, then transpose it_ and how are you transposing it?

Comment: @dbf - then you select any other cell, right click, paste special, select Transpose

Comment: Transpose it from where to where? Are you manipulating an Excel spreadsheet? Is this data held in arrays? Where is it coming from and where are you putting it? Hint: flip the order of your loops.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13019329/1143495

Comment: @DaveRandom: I believe "transpose" means flipping rows for columns, and vice versa.

Comment: @halfer I know what it means from a functional point of view, it just doesn't mean anything unless you know where the data is coming from and where it is going (format wise)

Comment: @DaveRandom, gotcha. OP, Mark's answer should help you out - read the file in using a library, use his answer to transpose, then writing out as CSV should be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly difficult in PHP starting from an array

```
$startArray = array(
    array('Animal','','',''),
    array('Mamals','','Birds',''),
    array('Whales','Humans','Eagle','Hen'),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($startArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $result[$key2][$key] = $value2;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

If you're starting from an Excel file, then you need a library like [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) to read the cells to an array, update the worksheet after the transpose, and write the file again