# PHP array handling

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to print the contents of a table so that only the 4 latest entries are displayed.

```
$query = "SELECT `field1`, `field2` ,`field3`,`field4`  FROM myTable 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4 ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {print_r($row);}
```

this returns the following for each requested entry (x4):

```
Array
(
[field1] => value
[field2] => value
[field3] => value
[field4] => value
)
```

what I want is to create an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[field1] => value1
[field1] => value2
[field1] => value3
[field1] => value4
)
```

I've tried this which looks to be correct but is not doing what I want, instead it's creating a new array for each entry:

```
$a = array($row);
$field1 = array_column($a, 'field1');
print_r($field1);
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm new to php.

Comment: The array you are asking for is invalid, you have four `field1` keys all the same...

Comment: Array/Object must have unique key.

Comment: it could be that I've not explained this very well, what I want for each field is: Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => value2 [2] => value3 etc )

Comment: currently returned are 4 arrays each containing values for four different fields; what I want is four arrays each with values for the same field.

Comment: Do you want this?  `print_r($row['field1']);`

Comment: I think you want this

`$arrName = [];    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { array_push($arrName, $row["field"]); }   print_r($arrName);`

Comment: not understand clearly what you want :( Maybe you should explain your issue with some more examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose MYSQL db in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019151/how-to-transpose-mysql-db-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
foreach($data as $f){
 $array['field1']=$f->value;
}
```

Comment: can you explain. Code only answers are rarely informative or helpful

Comment: Yes sure,  As per above requirement he want array key is same and value will be changed. So First I can define an array after that I am start foreach loop. In foreach loop I a can define default key and all store value in this array. If I am wrong so please tell me.

Comment: So... please **edit** your answer and add the details to the answer, rather than in an easily missable comment